# prevent the page from refreshing when adding items to the carte using angular

Tags: php, angular

I am trying to prevent the page from refreshing when I add items to the carte but any of the codes that i tried work. any suggestions please ?

i prefer the solution to be in angular or ajax . thank you

Comment: Can you provide the code you have tried and why it didn't work?

Comment: it was something like that <script>
  var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
  app.controller('myApp', function($scope) {
    $scope.formData = {};

    $scope.submitForm = function ($event) {
      $event.preventDefault();
    };
  });
</script>